# My sites INSERT and UPDATE script has ceased working

Tags: php, mysql

I am a complete Newb where this PHP malarkey is concerned, however I have picked up a few basics and probably many more bad habits.

The problem I have is the INSERT script and the UPDATE scripts have ceased working on Friday, the last time I know the INSERT worked was Thursday as items are added pretty much daily without any problems.
All I have done is added 2 fields in the database 'salesperson' and 'live_date' and amended the scripts accordingly, when I realized it had stopped working I re-uploaded the original files and it still wasn't working, however I don't know if this is just coincidence or I've broken something.

I can't for the life of me see any errors in the script but what do I know, (actually I wish to re-phrase that, I can't see any errors that would cause this problem, I'm sure that there are plenty of errors in it ;-)

I would very much appreciate it if one of you experts could take a peek for me before I yank out what grey hair I have remaining.

Many thanks in advance.
Ian.

INSERT Script:

```
<?php 
//Connect to the MySQL database
include"../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { 
$meta_desc=addslashes($_POST['meta_desc']);
$sku=$_POST['sku'];
$salesperson=$_POST['salesperson'];
$business_name=addslashes($_POST['business_name']);
$address=$_POST['address'];
$package=addslashes($_POST['package']); 
$contact_name=addslashes($_POST['contact_name']);
$description=addslashes($_POST['description']);
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$e_mail=$_POST['e_mail'];
$short_web=$_POST['short_web'];
$weblink=$_POST['weblink'];
$facebook=$_POST['facebook'];
$first_ad=$_POST['first_ad'];
$main_menu=$_POST['main_menu'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
$sub_category=$_POST['sub_category'];
$niche_category=$_POST['niche_category'];
$display_ad=$_POST['display_ad'];
$live_date=addslashes($_POST['live_date']);
}

$sql=mysql_query( "INSERT INTO business_list (id, meta_desc, sku, salesperson, business_name, address, package, contact_name, description, phone, e_mail, short_web, weblink, facebook, first_ad, main_menu, category, sub_category, niche_category, display_ad, live_date) VALUES ('NULL', '$meta_desc', 'NULL', '$salesperson', '$business_name', '$address', '$package', '$contact_name', '$description', '$phone', '$e_mail', '$short_web', '$weblink', '$facebook', '$first_ad', '$main_menu', '$category', '$sub_category', '$niche_category', '$display_ad', '$live_date')");


$lastid=mysql_insert_id();
$sql=mysql_query ($sql) or die ('<p></p><p></p>Database successfully updated with all  the information relating to:<strong> ' . $business_name . ' </strong>, 
<p>USE THIS ID FOR AD IMAGE:<strong> ' . $lastid . ' </strong><form action="set_sku.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="set_sku">
<p>Now you need to update the SKU in the Database</P>
<label>INPUT ID HERE TO UPDATE SKU AND CONTINUE TO ADD THE IMAGES</label>
<input name="sku" type="text" maxlength="7" />
<input type="submit" value="Update SKU" />
</form>
</p>');
mysql_close()
?>
```

UPDATE Script:

```
<?php 
include"../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { 
$ud_id=$_POST['ud_id'];
$ud_sku=$_POST['ud_sku'];
$ud_live_date=addslashes($_POST['ud_live_date']);
$ud_business_name=addslashes($_POST['ud_business_name']);
$ud_address=addslashes($_POST['ud_address']);
$ud_package=addslashes($_POST['ud_package']);
$ud_contact_name=addslashes($_POST['ud_contact_name']);
$ud_description=addslashes($_POST['ud_description']);
$ud_meta_desc=addslashes($_POST['ud_meta_desc']);
$ud_phone=$_POST['ud_phone'];
$ud_e_mail=$_POST['ud_e_mail'];
$ud_short_web=$_POST['ud_short_web'];
$ud_weblink=$_POST['ud_weblink'];
$ud_facebook=$_POST['ud_facebook'];
$ud_first_ad=$_POST['ud_first_ad'];
$ud_category=$_POST['ud_category'];
$ud_sub_category=$_POST['ud_sub_category'];
$ud_niche_category=$_POST['ud_niche_category'];
$ud_display_ad=$_POST['ud_display_ad'];
$ud_salesperson=$_POST['ud_salesperson'];
}

$query="UPDATE business_list SET sku='$ud_sku', live_date='$ud_live_date', business_name='$ud_business_name', address='$ud_address', package='$ud_package', contact_name='$ud_contact_name', description='$ud_description', meta_desc='$ud_meta_desc', phone='$ud_phone', e_mail='$ud_e_mail', short_web='$ud_short_web', weblink='$ud_weblink', facebook='$ud_facebook', first_ad='$ud_first_ad', main_menu='$ud_main_menu', category='$ud_category', sub_category='$ud_sub_category', niche_category='$ud_niche_category', display_ad='$ud_display_ad', salesperson='$ud_salesperson' WHERE id='$ud_id'";

mysql_query($query); 
echo "Record Updated";
mysql_close();
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SLBD - Admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>

<?php include_once("../templates/template_header.php"); ?>

<h1> <?php echo "Record Updated"; ?></h1>

<div id="contact" class="request">
<a href="log_out.php">[Log Out]</a> | <a href="reports_asc.php"> [Reports]</a>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="40">
<tr><strong>
<form action="admin.php" method="get" name="id">    
<td align="center">    
<input type="submit" value="Add an Advert" />
</td>
</form>  

<form action="imageadmin.php">    
<td align="center">   
<input type="submit" value="Add or Update an Image" />
</td>
</form> 

<form action="admin_update.php" method="get" name="id"> 
<td align="center"> 
<label>Update Ad with ID?</label><br /><br />
<input name="id" type="text" size="5" maxlength="7">   <br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Update Advert" />
</td>  
</form>
  </strong> 
</tr> 
</table>

</div>
<br />
<?php include_once("../templates/template_footer.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The CONNECT Script works fine because:

- the site displays correctly and uses the same script
- The `UPDATE` command collects the data, just won't do the `UPDATE`

Comment: What does `$sql` echo out jsut prior to being executed?

Comment: Show the definition of the table in db. If you've added fields and they don't have default values the old scripts won't work.

Comment: The tutorial you picked must be so outdated that its author must have known the queen Victoria in person.

Comment: HaHa, I did tell you that you'd find lots of errors, $sql tells me that the database has been updated when I know it hasn't, the $lastid tells me zero if it failed and the row id if it succeeded, the reason this works this way is because I need to update the sku for the review script, probably long winded way to do it but please remember I had to work most of this stuff out myself with no php experience.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by show the definition of the table in db, the script 'connect_to_mysql.php' has that? everything else works just not the form to insert new Advert or update an Advert.  The db fields added are salesperson which has a default value of 'Gabi' and the date field doesn't. Please remember that when this script failed I FTP'd the old one and it still didn't work even though it did the day before.

Answer (score 0):

Your using a deprecated ***MySQL***. Lets convert your work to ***MySQLi***

**INSERT** page:

```
<?php 

/* WE'LL START OF BY ESTABLISHING YOUR CONNECTION */

$connection=mysqli_connect("Host","Username","Password","Database");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['skusubmit'])){ /* IF BUTTON IS CLICKED */

$meta_desc=addslashes($_POST['meta_desc']);
$sku=$_POST['sku'];
$salesperson=$_POST['salesperson'];
$business_name=addslashes($_POST['business_name']);
$address=$_POST['address'];
$package=addslashes($_POST['package']); 
$contact_name=addslashes($_POST['contact_name']);
$description=addslashes($_POST['description']);
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$e_mail=$_POST['e_mail'];
$short_web=$_POST['short_web'];
$weblink=$_POST['weblink'];
$facebook=$_POST['facebook'];
$first_ad=$_POST['first_ad'];
$main_menu=$_POST['main_menu'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
$sub_category=$_POST['sub_category'];
$niche_category=$_POST['niche_category'];
$display_ad=$_POST['display_ad'];
$live_date=addslashes($_POST['live_date']);

/* START THE INSERT QUERY */

mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO business_list (id, meta_desc, sku, salesperson, business_name, address, package, contact_name, description, phone, e_mail, short_web, weblink, facebook, first_ad, main_menu, category, sub_category, niche_category, display_ad, live_date) VALUES ('NULL', '$meta_desc', 'NULL', '$salesperson', '$business_name', '$address', '$package', '$contact_name', '$description', '$phone', '$e_mail', '$short_web', '$weblink', '$facebook', '$first_ad', '$main_menu', '$category', '$sub_category', '$niche_category', '$display_ad', '$live_date')");

echo "Database successfully updated with all  the information relating to: <strong>". $business_name;

} /* END OF ISSET */

/* SUBMIT ON ITSELF */
echo "<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
echo "<p>Now you need to update the SKU in the Database</P>";
echo "<label>INPUT ID HERE TO UPDATE SKU AND CONTINUE TO ADD THE IMAGES</label>";
echo "<input name='sku' type='text' maxlength='7' />";
/* PLEASE CONTINUE HERE THE OTHER INPUT FIELDS NEEDED */
echo "<input type='submit' value='Update SKU' name='skusubmit' />";
echo "</form>";

?>
```

Here's your **UPDATE** page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SLBD - Admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>

<?php 

    /* WE'LL START OF BY ESTABLISHING YOUR CONNECTION */

    $connection=mysqli_connect("Host","Username","Password","Database");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

    echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
    }

if (isset($_POST['updatesubmit'])) { 

$ud_id=$_POST['ud_id'];
$ud_sku=$_POST['ud_sku'];
$ud_live_date=addslashes($_POST['ud_live_date']);
$ud_business_name=addslashes($_POST['ud_business_name']);
$ud_address=addslashes($_POST['ud_address']);
$ud_package=addslashes($_POST['ud_package']);
$ud_contact_name=addslashes($_POST['ud_contact_name']);
$ud_description=addslashes($_POST['ud_description']);
$ud_meta_desc=addslashes($_POST['ud_meta_desc']);
$ud_phone=$_POST['ud_phone'];
$ud_e_mail=$_POST['ud_e_mail'];
$ud_short_web=$_POST['ud_short_web'];
$ud_weblink=$_POST['ud_weblink'];
$ud_facebook=$_POST['ud_facebook'];
$ud_first_ad=$_POST['ud_first_ad'];
$ud_category=$_POST['ud_category'];
$ud_sub_category=$_POST['ud_sub_category'];
$ud_niche_category=$_POST['ud_niche_category'];
$ud_display_ad=$_POST['ud_display_ad'];
$ud_salesperson=$_POST['ud_salesperson'];

mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE business_list SET sku='$ud_sku', live_date='$ud_live_date', business_name='$ud_business_name', address='$ud_address', package='$ud_package', contact_name='$ud_contact_name', description='$ud_description', meta_desc='$ud_meta_desc', phone='$ud_phone', e_mail='$ud_e_mail', short_web='$ud_short_web', weblink='$ud_weblink', facebook='$ud_facebook', first_ad='$ud_first_ad', main_menu='$ud_main_menu', category='$ud_category', sub_category='$ud_sub_category', niche_category='$ud_niche_category', display_ad='$ud_display_ad', salesperson='$ud_salesperson' WHERE id='$ud_id'");

echo "Record Updated";

} /* END OF ISSET SUBMIT */

include_once("../templates/template_header.php"); ?>

<h1> <?php echo "Record Update"; ?></h1>

<div id="contact" class="request">
<a href="log_out.php">[Log Out]</a> | <a href="reports_asc.php"> [Reports]</a>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="40">
<tr><strong>
<form action="" method="get" name="id">

<td align="center"> 
<label>Update Ad with ID?</label><br /><br />
<input name="id" type="text" size="5" maxlength="7">   <br /><br />
<?php /* ADD HERE THE OTHER TEXTBOX. ASSIGN THE CORRESPONDING NAME FOR THEM */ ?>
<input type="submit" value="Update Advert" name="updatesubmit"/>
</td>  
</form>
</strong> 
</tr> 
</table>

</div>
<br />
<?php include_once("../templates/template_footer.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```